# как сделать так что бы при нажатии на кнопку персонаж прыгал?

Tags: unity3d

написал код о самом прыжке и на проверку есть ли под ногами земля.
на сам спрайт повесил button кинул своего перса и метод на прыжок в спрайт, однако ничего неработает, я знаю что нужно написать функцию о том что при нажатии на кнопку перс должен прыгать, но незнаю как
сцена: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

скрипт:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если это код из какого-то урока, то я не советую его смотреть дальше, а найти замену. Официальный курс от Unity подойдет лучше, чем другие.

Во-первых, вы пытаетесь определить столкновение с объектом, вызывая метод `OnJumpButton` в `Update`. Но ведь `OnJumpButton` должен вызываться только, когда кнопка прыжка нажата.

Во-вторых, вы при передвижении персонажа двигаете его через `transform`, а при прыжке через `Rigidbody`. Так делать не следует, используйте что-то одно(Rigidbody).

В-третьих, про метод `AddForce` можете забыть, он не нужен для перемещения персонажа.

Далее покажу и расскажу как сделать все правильнее.

```
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody2D))]
public class Hero : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Vector2 _jumpVelocity; // Ускорение при прыжке
    [SerializeField] private float _runSpeed; // скорость персонажа
    private bool _isGrounded = false;
    private Rigidbody2D _rb;

    private void Awake()
    {
        _rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        var horizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        Run(horizontal);
    }

    private void OnCollisionStay2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        foreach(var i in collision.contacts)
        {
            if (i.normal.y > 0.8)
            {
                _isGrounded = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        _isGrounded = false;
    }

    public void Jump()
    {
        if (_isGrounded)
        {
            _rb.velocity += _jumpVelocity;
        }
    }


    private void Run(float direction)
    {
        if (direction == 0) return;
        if (_isGrounded == false) return;

        var velocity = _rb.velocity;
        velocity.x = _runSpeed * direction;
        _rb.velocity = velocity;
    }

}
```

По-порядку:

`[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody2D))]` нужно для того, чтобы на скрипте в любом случае был компонент `Rigidbody2D`. Если этого компонента не будет, то он автоматически добавится.

`[SerializeField]` Этот атрибут нужен для того, чтобы видеть приватные поля в инспекторе и иметь возможность их менять.

`_rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();` Здесь получаем компонент `RigidBody`, который навешан на объект. Обязательно делайте `[RequireComponent(typeof(ТипКомпонента))]`, если получаете его через `GetComponent`.

В апдейте мы получаем значения горизонтальной оси и вызываем метод `Run()`.

`OnCollisionStay2D` вызывается, пока есть столкновение с каким-либо коллайдером. Здесь мы в цикле проходим все точки соприкосновения и, если нормаль этой точки проходит через ограничение, то присваиваем значение true полю `_isGrounded`. Что такое нормаль, можете загуглить.

`OnCollisionExit2D` вызывается, когда объекты перестают соприкосаться. Здесь просто меняет `_isGrounded` на false.

`Jump` здесь все просто. Если персонаж на земле, то добавляем к ускорению значение поля `_jumpVelocity`. Не забудьте указать значение для этого поля в инспекторе. На кнопку прыжка этот метод навешивается точно так же, как и ваш.

`Run(float direction)` здесь все тоже предельно просто. Не делаем ничего, если направление равно нулю и персонаж в воздухе. В ином случае берем то, что указано в поле `_runSpeed` и умножаем на направление движения (Если direction будет отрицательным, то движение будет в противоположную сторону), далее просто присваиваем это все ускорению персонажа по оси X.

Ну и, естественно, на персонаже должен висеть компонент `Rigidbody2D` и любой коллайдер, а на земле просто коллайдер.

Как поворачивать спрайт, думаю сами разберетесь.

Comment: Спасибо огромное мне очень понравилось то как персонаж стал прыгать. Я уже незнал что делать, можно ли задать тебе 1 вопрос? ну я все же задам, извиняюсь за наглость. есть ли на нормальные курсы на юнити в русском интернете?

Comment: Про курсы не знаю, но подскажу пару каналов по юнити на YT.  [Максим Крюков](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCCrLQKMtF_FwOeDgTUuOksw), [Emerald Powder](https://www.youtube.com/c/EmeraldPowder), [Роман Сакутин](https://www.youtube.com/c/GamedevelopingRu1). Есть еще канал про C#, но там темы немного посложнее - [Дмитрий Нестерук](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCJIlkaXVl-6vU3ghQkr51nQ). По архитектуре - [S0ER](https://www.youtube.com/c/S0ERDEVS). Главное не смотри всяких Хауди-хо и других "популяризаторов it".

Comment: спасибо большое. У меня правда есть еще одна просьба, заранее извиняюсь за свою навязчивость но мог бы ты подсказать как в твоем коде сделать еще и хождение на клавиши. я просто хочу выпустить 1 игру по тому гайду(потому что он единственный на ру ютубе с такой игрой которую я хочу) чисто ради эксперимента сколько она соберет скачиваний, а дальше уже начать изучать юнити. Еще раз извиняюсь за все это.

Comment: Если нужно, чтобы персонаж двигался, когда удерживаешь кнопку из UI, то нужно писать свой скрипт кнопки, обычная кнопка поддерживает только нажатие. Используй `UnityEngine.EventSystems` и `UnityEngine.Events`. Унаследуй скрипт от `MonoBehaviour`, чтобы можно было его навешать на спрайт кнопки, реализуй интерфейсы `IPointerDownHandler, IPointerUpHandler`, первый отвечает за нажатие кнопки, второй за отпускание. Вызывай `UnityEvent` в момент, когда кнопка нажата, но не отпущена. Вызывать метод `Run` из скрипта героя точно так же, как и с прыжком, только сделай метод `public`.

Comment: спасибо большое